# Serialize a hashmap to a json in a certain feilds in JAVA

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I need to serialize a map to a json in a certain order.

This is the map

> HashMap<String, String> dataMap = {
> "CompanyCode": "4",
> "EntyyCode": "2002296",
> "SubEntityCode": "000",
> "ContractNumber": "52504467115",
> "Progressive Contract": "0",
> "DocumentNumber": "200003333494028",
> "LogonUserName": "AR333",
> "Progressive Title": "0"
> }

This is the json model I would like:

```
{
     "Policy": {
         "ContractNumber": "52504467115",
         "ProgressiveContract": "0"
     },
     "Title": {
         "LogonUserName": "AR333",
         "ProgressiveTitle": "0"
     },
     "BusinessChannel": {
         "CompanyCode": "4",
         "EntyyCode": "2002296",
         "SubEntityCode": "000"
     },
     "Document": {
         "DocumentNumber": "200003333494028"
     }
}
```

I need to convert this map into a JSON string. I know that this can be done using Jackson as below:

> new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map);

How do I do this using Jackson? Or is there any other way to do this in Java?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the solution you request contains a second problem: partition. Not only must the items contain a particular order, but they must also somehow be divided over different categories. In Java, these categories usually correspond to their own classes or, since recently, records. Then the top level class (corresponding to the unnamed outer object of the JSON) determines ordering, as so (the name `Contract` is my choice):

```
record Contract(
        Policy policy, 
        Title title, 
        BusinessChannel businessChannel, 
        Document document )
{
}
```

with each of the properties of Contract having their own class, e.g.:

```
record Policy( String contractNumber, int progressiveContract )
```

etc.
Serializing Contract then recursively serializes each of its parameters, with the required outcome as the result.
This would be the 'standard' way.

So, since you start with a `HashMap`, which by contract offers no guarantee of ordering, let alone an easy way to partition its contents into sub-objects, you could try two things:

- Rethink the use of a map. Switching to the class structure takes care of the structure automatically.
- Manually stream and convert the values in order (or use e.g. a `TreeMap` with custom `Comparator`) and then partition the values themselves. This probably requires more work than a map saves.